# Debian preseeding and UEFI

Tags: debian, uefi, preseed

I have the following preseed snippet for installing a Debian (Jessie) system on a single partition:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

This works just as I want, everything is just overwritten, no questions asked. The only problem is that it doesn't work on a UEFI system. (In my testing the installer succeeds, but the resulting system doesn't have a UEFI partition and hence doesn't boot.)

Does `partman` support preseeding for an UEFI install, and in that case, how do I do it?